# Is it possible to create a List field without requiring Allowed Values?

Tags: entities

It there any way to create a List field that doesn't require an Allowed Values list?  I'm looking for a free form list, which users can typing values in or I can programmatically add values without the requirement of them having to be in an Allowed Values list.

I'm looking for something a bit more sophisticated than a delimited textarea field so that suggestion doesn't apply here.  I want the functionality of a List field but not the requirement of the Allowed Values validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Select (or other)](https://drupal.org/project/select_or_other)  module for this.

Project pays says:

> Provides a new Forms API element which is a select/radios/checkboxes
>   element that has an 'other' option. When 'other' is selected a
>   textfield appears for the user to provide a custom value.

You may also try [CCK Select Other](https://drupal.org/project/cck_select_other)

Comment: These are interesting and close to what I'm needing but both seem to offer only a single additional option that the user can type in.  I'm looking for a multiple entry field (cardinality: unlimited) which can have several unique values in it.

Comment: If you want it with  multiple entry field (cardinality: unlimited) so Update your question with this requirement